# Parsing JSON with different level Nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am having a difficult time simply appending data to an element from a JSON file. I have the following

[Link to JSON](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Here is the jQuery I am trying to use -

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=:isbn=0-13-727827-6',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data.items, function(index){
            $(".tab1").append("<div>"+data.title+"</div>");
        });
    }
});
```

From the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fd778/1/)

You can see I am going wrong! I am looking to pull the title of the book from `Item->volumeInfo->title` Every time I try to reference the node volumeInfo i get an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` here is the top level object, not each item you are trying to loop through. JQuery `each` function provides two parameters, index, and current item you are looping though. So use the second parameter instead:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=:isbn=0-13-727827-6',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data.items, function(index, item){
            $(".tab1").append("<div>"+item.volumeInfo.title+"</div>");
        });
    }
});
```